# create 100 small Iframes in one webpage using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to create a webpage in my website , where I can put my 100 blogs in Iframes using javascript for loop .
When I open  page then It should be open many small url Iframes and open urls like http://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/1
http://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/2
http://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/3
............
 http://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/100 
its easy to open in new window but i need in one page .
Thanks .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var i;
    var launch_code;

    for ( var i = 000001; i < 000020; i++) {
        launch_code = "https://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/"+ i;

    window.open(launch_code, '_blank', "width=200, height=100");
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show what you have done and show what is not working. Provide your code (or at least some sample code). If what you are asking is for someone to write some code for you to see how this is done, Stack Overflow is not the place for that kind of question.

Comment: Please don't do this. "Iframes provide an easy way to embed content from one web site into another. But they should be used cautiously."

Comment: Dear sir .. I want this type of for loop code . I wanna test in website for learning purpose . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as user experience goes, this is not a good idea.

Nonetheless, you would do this by adding the HTML for each iframe to an accumulating string, and then setting the string to be your page's innerHTML.

You should also add a div to contain the iframes (in my example below I used `<div id="page"></div>`) otherwise, with the way you've laid out your code by having the script within the `body` tags, you could end up overwriting your own code.

```js
var pageContent = "";
for ( var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
 var urlNumber = ("00000" + i).slice(-6); // pads with leading zeros
 pageContent += '<iframe src="http://www.rathorehomi.com/blog/' + urlNumber + '"></iframe>';
}
document.getElementById( 'page' ).innerHTML = pageContent;
```

```css
#page {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
iframe {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
</div>
```